# Is it OK to say "There is no problem if you do it next week."?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

I need to reply to a commercial email where my "colleague" says that he we will do the job next week.

Is it good English to say "There is no problem if you do it next week." ?
Is there another way to say it ?

Edit: Would this one be better : "It sounds good to me if you do this next week. " ?

Answer (score 1):

It seem more natural to say "*It's* no problem if you do it next week."

If I am not 100% sure, I might soften the statement by saying "There should be no problems if you do it next week.", "I can't see any problems with you doing it next week." or ""Next week should be no problem."

If the context is clear, it could be made more casual and relaxed with: "No problem" (or in Australia, "No worries")

Answer (score 0):

The first one seems fine, not sure about the second one though.

You might say "Next week sounds good to me".

Answer (score 0):

"That is perfectly acceptable. Thank you for your reply."

Answer (score -3):

"That's okay if you do this in next week" or "even you do this in next week, there's no problem" is better

Comment: neither of these are grammatical english sentences